# Does anyone know what kind of storage card this is?

Tags: memory-card

I've looked all over google, I couldn't figure where kind of card this is. I got it from a travel service, it's suppose to have our photos on it.

[image]

Comment: How big is it? Can you take a picture of it with something else we know the size of (like a MicroSD card, USB drive, etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion its just a USB flash drive.

Comment: I agree... A -really- cheap one.

Comment: It's the size of a micro sd card but thicker.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a usb! Turns out I had to leave it in the card it comes with to fit the size of the usb slot.

[image]

[image]